# Zoom In Keyboard Shorcut Changed In ML

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have MacBook Pro and in Lion for zoomIn I used control + trackpad up. now it has changed. How can I changed it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the install update of Mountain Lion disabled that feature. You can re-enable it in:

*System Preferences > Accessibility > Zoom > Use scroll gesture with modifier keys to zoom*